# Weird mysql, showing 0 result set from myAdmin, but returns rows in PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this query which I run in phpMyAdmin

```
SELECT m.msgFrom, m.msgTo, m.msgID, m.subject, m.dateTime, a.username
FROM mailbox m
JOIN accounts a ON ( a.id = IF( m.msgTo =1, m.msgFrom, m.msgTo ) ) 
WHERE msgTo =1
OR msgFrom =1
AND parentID =0
AND IF( m.msgTo =1, m.fromDelete, m.toDelete ) !=1
ORDER BY DATETIME DESC 
LIMIT 250
```

And I get a rowset of 0.

When using it with PDO PHP and placeholders like so,

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("
SELECT m.msgFrom, m.msgTo, m.msgID, m.subject, m.dateTime, a.username 
FROM mailbox m JOIN accounts a ON (a.id = IF(m.msgTo = ?, m.msgFrom, m.msgTo)) 
WHERE msgTo = ? OR msgFrom = ? AND parentID = 0 AND IF(m.msgTo = ?, m.fromDelete, m.toDelete) != 1 
ORDER BY dateTime DESC LIMIT 250");
$q -> execute(array($user['id'], $user['id'], $user['id'], $user['id']));
```

I get a rowset of 1 where `$user[id'] == 1`.

What is going on here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you get the expected result when running the un-placeholdered query via PDO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AND have an stronger binding than OR in mysql

```
WHERE msgTo =1
OR msgFrom =1
AND parentID =0
AND IF( m.msgTo =1, m.fromDelete, m.toDelete ) !=1
```

means

```
WHERE msgTo =1
OR (msgFrom =1
AND parentID =0
AND IF( m.msgTo =1, m.fromDelete, m.toDelete ) !=1)
```

PDO maybe handles this in another way

try

```
WHERE (msgTo =1
OR msgFrom =1)
AND parentID =0
AND IF( m.msgTo =1, m.fromDelete, m.toDelete ) !=1
```

in phpmyadmin

Comment: PDO does not perform any manipulation of the query or of the resulting data, outside of filling in the placeholders if prepared statement emulation is enabled.  It would not and could not change the actual logic of the query.

Comment: While the logic change in the SQL does fix the problem, PDO is not at fault here.

Comment: @Charles: You are correct. OP even commented that taking the exact SQL used in phpMyAdmin and using it with PDO, i.e., hardcoded values instead of parameters markers, **also returned zero rows**. So, of course, it was his SQL (and the assumed cause) that was wrong from the start. The answerer's suggestion that PDO or PMA manipulates comparison operations should be readily ignored.